# Is my usage of "any different" correct in this context?

Tags: grammar, context

I'm reading a Webnovel and in this particular chapter, there is this guy who is on a high position and everyone around him(not including those who have a higher authority and status) is bending over to his authority and status.

And someone commented about if it ever crossed these kind of people's minds about everyone not existing simply to bend over for them or if their ego is big enough to bend reality itself.

So I replied to that, pointing out that everyone the guy has met who have a lower authority and status than him have been bending over to his whims and demands thus far therefore he isn't in the wrong to think that a newcomer won't do the same.

Here is what I wrote:

- *People of lower status than him have been bending over to his whims thus far so logically speaking he isn't in the wrong to think that ZY will be any different.*

Note: ZY is an acronym for the newcomer's full name.

The first time I wrote my comment, I thought nothing of it but I have a habit of re-reading whatever I write online because English is my 3rd language and I guess I got tired of having to get whatever I say/write discredited simply because my English skill isn't up to par.

Anyways is what I wrote correct in this context? given what I wanted to convey.

Comment: Compare: "He has no reason to think that ZY will be any different"; "He isn't in the wrong (i.e., he's right; he has a reason) to think that ZY will be any different." I have no issue with your use of "any different"; instead, I think the phrasing suggests the opposite of what you mean. If I kept your phrasing but tweaked it to fit what I think you meant, I'd write: "he isn't in the wrong to think that ZY **won't** be any different." Does that make sense?

Comment: _Be any different_ is a predicate containing a negative polarity term (_any_) as a quantifier (cf _be very/a little/a lot/greatly/a bit different_. The NPI is licensed by the negative in the higher clause: _he **isn't** in the wrong to think that ZY will be **any** different_. The fact that _wrong_ is also negative and contradicts _isn't_ is confusing, but once a clause has a negative field, it can license NPIs, whether they make sense or not. Negation is used for emphasis more often than not.

Comment: @JohnLawler An honest question If I may? I don't understand how "he isn't(is not) in the wrong" is contradictory and confusing? I've seen this phrase used multiple times. Mostly, in the sense to justify that someone's actions isn't necessarily right but in the circumstances given they are not necessarily wrong either if this makes sense.

In this context, although he is not right to assume people will just bend over to his every whim and demand but thus far everyone has been doing so, so logically speaking he is not wrong to think that a new comer will react differently.

Comment: _He isn't in the wrong_ means _He's right_. The negatives cancel out; that's the contradiction I was speaking of. It's normal, if complex; the Latin rule is _Duplex negatio confirmat_ 'Double negation confirms'. This is not always true, but in this case it is.

Comment: I suppose I'd toy with 'Most people of lower status than him have been bending over to his whims thus far, so ,,,,' The 'most' to be realistic, the comma to facilitate parsing // breathing for narrators.

Comment: "Bending over to his whims" is better expressed as *bending to his whims* or maybe *will*. One is compliance, the other, accepting unwelcome intrusions.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *Be any different* is a predicate containing a negative polarity term (*any*) as a quantifier (cf *be very/a little/a lot/greatly/a bit different*. The NPI is licensed by the negative in the higher clause: *he **isn't** in the wrong to think that ZY will be **any** different*. The fact that *wrong* is also negative and contradicts *isn't* is confusing, but once a clause has a negative field, it can license NPIs, whether they make sense or not. Negation is used for emphasis more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify things using behave instead of be:
"(...) *he isn't in the wrong to think that ZY will* **behave** *any different*."

Comment: Switching to behave is a good idea. Then I'd go with *behave differently*. Also, *bending over* might be more sexual than intended. Because it is.